Make Angular checkbox halo / ripple disappear after mouse out?
Angular checkbox onclick  to make it deselected, the halo is not disappearing after mouse out. How can I make it disappear?
as seen at, uncheck and the halo remains after I move the mouse away.
https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview


it is a focus indicator. it shows your that the element is in focus and if you press "space" the checked/unchecked state will be altered. i.e. you can manipulate focus after clicking checkbox programmatically, but why would you do that?
